# Can't get headerBackImage to work in react-navigation 5.x.x

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to implement a custom image for the back button. I am using react-navigation 5.x.x. This is my AppNavigator:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

class MyCustomHeaderBackImage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Image
          source={require('../../../res/images/back-button.png')}
          style={{width: 22, height: 22, tintColor: '#f00'}}
        />
    );
  }
}

function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Screen1">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Screen1"
          component={Screen1}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Screen2"
          component={Screen2}
          options={{
            headerBackTitleVisible: false,
            title: '',
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: colors.blue,
              shadowColor: 'transparent',
            },
            headerBackImage: <MyCustomHeaderBackImage/>,
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

With this code, when I access `Screen2`, it fails with the message `backImage is not a function`

What other options I have tried:

1. Changing the code to: `headerBackImage: () => (<MyCustomHeaderBackImage/>)`. This fails with the message `Invariant violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string but got: object`
2. Using an `<Image />` instead of `MyCustomHeaderBackImage` and trying different types of calls e.g. `headerBackImage: () => (<Image source={require('../../../res/images/email.png')} />)`
3. Following the exact implementation from https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/2c7187b22aeff1cdec5ca6aeebb40c9c798c0888/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/StackWithCustomHeaderBackImage.js - only that I used `options` instead of `navigationOptions`, as I am using react-navigation 5.x.x.

Unfortunately, none of the methods above worked. Any ideas on how I can use a custom image for the back button?

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on `headerBackImage` as I could never get it to work. I think RN5 is still a bit buggy. Anyhow, I worked around it with a custom header component like this:

```
 const MyCustomHeaderBackImage = () => (
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", marginLeft: 4 }}>
    <Image source={require("../images/backArrow.png")} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
  </View>
);
```

Then in the stack navigator I added this in to the stack component:

```
  <Stack.Screen
      name="Screen Name"
      component={ScreenIWantToUse}
      options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        headerBackTitleVisible: false,
        headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchType onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", marginLeft: 4 }}>
                <MyCustomHeaderBackImage />
                <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 20 }}>Back</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchType>
        ),
        headerTitleStyle: { fontSize: 25, color: "#fff" },
        headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#333" },
       
  .... etc
```

`headerLeft` over-rides the default button.

Meanwhile, back in the real world, I used Platform to require either a chevron image for iOS with the word "Back" or, for Android, a left pointing arrow in the custom component. Then in the `headerLeft` function I also used Platform to show a view for either platform, like this:

```
  const MyCustomHeaderBackImage = () => (
   <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", marginLeft: 4 }}>
     <Image source={Platform.OS === "ios" ? require("../images/backArrow.png") : require("../images/backArrowAndroid.png")} style={{ width: 20, height: 20 }} />
   </View>
 );
```

then this...

```
  headerLeft: () => (
          Platform.OS === "ios" ?
            <TouchType onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", marginLeft: 4 }}>
                <MyCustomHeaderBackImage />
                <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 20 }}>Back</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchType>
            :
            <TouchType onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "center", paddingLeft: 8, width: 50, height: 50 }}>
                <MyCustomHeaderBackImage />
              </View>
            </TouchType>
        ),
   ...etc
```

I find it really annoying the the docs give you a method but never show you how to use it. Anyway, it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works. The Cross is the component where I have the image. It can also be done in the options of each screen .

```
screenOptions: {{
    headerBackImage: () => <Cross style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} />
}}
```